# Prove an operation is associative

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Given multiplication on natural number s.t. a * b = r where r is the remainder when the product of ab is divided by divisor n.

I need to show that the operation is associative. Based on the definition of the associative, I get (a * b) * c = [c(ab % n)] % n and a (b * c) = [a(bc % n)] % n. How can I proceed? Is c(ab % n) = a(bc % n)?

Comment: The edits made by User203940 were invalid. $\pmod n$ is *NOT* an operator and putting this in terms of modulo *equivalences* is not the same as the $*$ operation as defined.  The question as User203940 editted it is a completely different question.

Comment: No  $c(ab\%n) \ne a(bc\%n)$.  But $a*b$ is *not* $a(b\% n)$ either; it is $(ab)\%n$ which is different.  You have to prove that $(ab)\%n =[ (a\%n)(b\% n)]\% n$.  Once you prove that everything will work beautifully.  The $a*(b*c)=a*((bc)\%n)=(a[bc\%n])\%n=(a\%n)(bc\%n)\%n=[(a\%n)(b\%n)(c\%n)]\%n$ and by similar manipulation $(a*b)*c= (ab\%n)*c=[(ab\%n)c]\%n=([(a\%n)(b\%n)]\%n)(c\%n)\%n=[(a\%n)(b\%n)(c\%n)]\%n$.

Comment: Actually let me redo that last comment:  $a*b =(ab)\%$.  You need to prove that $(ab)\%n = [(a\%n)(b\%n)]\%n$.  Once you prove that you are good.  Then it's easy to show.   $a*(b*c) = [a((bc)\% n)]\%n = [(a\%n)((b\%n)(c\%n)\%n)]\%n=([(a\%n)(b\%n)(c\%n)]\%n)\%n=[(a\%n)(b\%n)(c\%n)]\%n$ and $(a*b)*c = ([(ab)\%n]c)\%n=(((a\%n)(b\%n)(c\%n))\%n)\%n=[(a\%n)(b\%n)(c\%n)]\%n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to notice is if $p$ and $q$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$ then for any $d$, $dp$ and $dq$ will have the same remainders.

Pf:  Let $p= kn + r_1$ and $q=jn + r_1$ where $r_1$ is the remainder of $p$ and $q$.  Let $a = mn+r_2$ where $r_2$ is the remainder of $a$.  ANd let's do a premptive strike and assume that $r_1r_2 = vn + s$ where $s$ is the remainder of $r_1r_2$.

Now we just do it.

$ap = (mn+r_2)(kn+r_1) = mkn^2 + r_2kn + r_1mn + r_1r_2 = n(mkn +r_2k + r_1m) + vn + s = n(mkn+r_2k + r_1m + v) + s$

and $s$ is the remainder of $ap$.

And $aq=(mn+r_2)(jn+r_1) = mjn^2 + r_2jn + r_1mn + r_1r_2 = n(mjn +r_2j + r_1m) + vn + s = n(mjn+r_2j + r_1m + v) + s$

and $s$ is the remainder of $aq$.

....

And now we can prove that $*$ is associative.

Suppose $a$ has remainder $a'$ and $b$ has remainder $b'$ and $c$ has remainder $c'$.

Not $a$ and $a'$ both have $a'$ as a remainder and $b$ and $b'$ have $b'$ as remainder and $c$ and $c'$ have $c'$ as a remainder.

So $(a*b)*c = $[remainder of ($ab$)]$*c = $[remainder of ($ab'$)$*c =$[remainder of ($a'b'$)$*c =$[remainder of (remainder of $(a'b')$)$\cdot c$]=[remainder of $(a'b')\cdot c$]$ =$

[remainder of $(a'b'c)$]=[remainder of $(a'b'c')$]

And likewise:

$a*(b*c)= a*$[remainder of $bc$]=$a*$[remainder of $b'c$]=$a*$[remainder of $b'c'$]=

[remainder of ($a\cdot $[remainder of $b'c'$])]=

[remainder of ($a \cdot (b'c')$)]=

[remainder of ($a'b'c'$)]$.

And that's that

$(a*b)*c = a*(b*c) = $remainder of $a'b'c'$